# AngularJs: unable to toggle the visibility of two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using this approach:

**app.js**

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['fsCordova']);

    app.controller('MyController', function($scope, CordovaService) {

        this.ready = false;

        CordovaService.ready.then(function() {

            console.log ("CordovaService.ready received");
            this.ready = true;
        });

    });

})();
```

**I *can* see in console the message *CordovaService.ready received*. So the code is working.**

In my **index.html** I've this (only usefull portion).

```
    <body ng-controller="MyController">
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening" ng-hide="ready">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received"  ng-show="ready">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Just for mattar of completeness, this is the relevant part of .css file

```
.event.listening {
    background-color:#333333;
}

.event.received {
    background-color:#4B946A;
}

.blink {
    animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
}
```

I'll repeat: **I *can* see in console the message *CordovaService.ready received*. So the js code is working.**

**The problem is that:** 'Connecting to Device" remains visible, even if MyController.ready is set to true.

How to debug?

Comment: and you cannot see 'Device is Ready' as well right?

Comment: exactly, I cannot see "Device is Ready"

Comment: Hve you tried what Alexandre had suggested?

Comment: I'm trying Vadim answer now, but, as I've commented, I've got a syntax error

Comment: the syntax for apply is incorrect it should be $scope.$apply(function(){});

Comment: See my last comment, a new error is happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$scope` to share state between controller an template.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'CordovaService', function($scope, CordovaService) {

    $scope.ready = false;
    CordovaService.ready.then(function() {
        console.log ("CordovaService.ready received");
        $scope.ready = true;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Also he can add controller prefix in template MyController.ready

Comment: What is a 'controller prefix' ?

Comment: @GenaMoroz Controller's namespace should not be used for properties that intent to be modified, only as namespace for functions that controller wants to expose as public API. It is usually done to enhance performance of scope digest cycle, since only scope members are watched. Placing values that intent to be modified and watched is a known anti pattern.

Comment: @Vadmin: i got 
'SyntaxError: missing : after property id'
in the row
'$scope.ready = true;'
Why ?

Comment: @realtebo Oh, my fault. I forgot `function()` when I pass callback to `$scope.$apply`. I fixed the post now, Thanks.

Comment: @Vadim: thanks, but now I got a strange error. See the error and official explanation here: http://tinyurl.com/m4hxetk - I must tiny this url because too long, sorry

Comment: The error says that digest cycle was already triggered somewhere else, probably `CordovaService` already called for `$scope.$apply`. You can try to remove `$scope.$apply` an leave only `$scope.ready = true;`. If it works, please add comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Vadim: using $scope.ready = true; without apply actually works !

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$scope.ready` instead of `this.ready`

Edit : My answer was quite short, here is an expanded version :

As the documentation says :

> Scope is the glue between application controller and the view

If you want to expose a variable and get the updated value inside your view, you new to use the $scope.
If you use `this`, you are referring to the local scope inside your controller only and the view has no way to know this variable.

Comment: Do you mind updating some details about the change? Why is it required ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the controller look like this:

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['fsCordova']);

    app.controller('MyController', ['$scope','CordovaService',function($scope, CordovaService) {

        $scope.ready = false;

        CordovaService.ready.then(function() {

            console.log ("CordovaService.ready received");
            $scope.ready = true;
        });

    }]);

})();
```

The actual reason why this.ready was not working inside CordovaService.ready.then(function() {}) function was the 'this' will take the scope of the current function that is that of CordovaService.ready.then(function() rather than the scope that is why your scope was not updating.

Comment: Your code will cause an error, since you tell to injector that you want to inject `CordovaService` as first argument ($scope) and the second argument (CordovaService) will be undefined